# angular2 universal - how to load underscore

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to work with unserscore.js.  How do I import?

```
npm install underscore --save


 import '../../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js';
 import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

In the console I get the below error

```
ERROR in [default] /Users/Documents/frontend/greenlabel-material/src/app/service/pager.service.ts:1:19 
    Cannot find module 'underscore'.
```

When I installed I had ang universal running and just did a reload.  I still got the above error but the code the used underscore worked.

When I kill the app and start again I still get the above but will not start.

```
~/Documents/frontend/dudelabel-material$ npm start 

> universal-starter@2.0.0 prestart /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/dudelabel-material
> npm run build


> universal-starter@2.0.0 prebuild /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/dudelabel-material
> rimraf dist


> universal-starter@2.0.0 build /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/dudelabel-material
> webpack

Hash: dcf119e1b8926b7b46a312a731c0c7486ac21b4c
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.25
Child
    Hash: dcf119e1b8926b7b46a3
    Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.25
    Time: 9393ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    index.js  4.23 MB       0  [emitted]  main
     [397] ./src async 160 bytes {0} [built]
        + 680 hidden modules

    ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/dudelabel-material/src/app/service/pager.service.ts:1:19 
    Cannot find module 'underscore'.
Child
    Hash: 12a731c0c7486ac21b4c
    Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.25
    Time: 4845ms
       Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    index.js  145 kB       0  [emitted]  main
        + 47 hidden modules

    ERROR in [default] /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/dudelabel-material/src/app/service/pager.service.ts:1:19 
    Cannot find module 'underscore'.

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.5.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! universal-starter@2.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the universal-starter@2.0.0 build script 'webpack'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the universal-starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs universal-starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls universal-starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/dudelabel-material/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.5.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! universal-starter@2.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the universal-starter@2.0.0 prestart script 'npm run build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the universal-starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs universal-starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls universal-starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/dude/Documents/frontend/dudelabel-material/npm-debug.log
```

So, how to make webpack, underscore work togeather?

Comment: Check if it appeared in package.json. Webpack gets module list from there, as I remember.